# How do I stop spotlight indexing the attachments in my mail (both sent and received)?

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app

I unchecked mail & messages in the spotlight preferences and also added the mail downloads folder to the exclude list but to no avail.

Comment: What OS version are you using?

Comment: Im using MacOS Sierra version 10.12.5